# StringUtils to split based on comma and space

Tags: java, regex, string, apache-stringutils

Could you please let me know whether we have any StringUtils function to split based on comma and space. Basically i am wondering whether we have any function which will split based on two delimiters. I have written custom function to do the same, but just checking whether we have any good function in any utils package.

The way I have done is to replace first delimiter with second one and then split based on second delimiter.

Comment: Did you consider the built-in `split`? e.g. `"some,random words".split("[, ]")`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this version of [`split`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), for example

```
String[] strings = StringUtils.split("some,random words", ", ");
```

or the built-in `split` method (as per my comment)

```
String[] strings = "some,random words".split("[, ]")?
```

Comment: Be aware that these methods don't behave always the same. I've noticed that the built-in split method doesn't return a (leading) empty element while StringUtils.split does.
Both don't return a trailing empty element.

Answer (score 1):

[`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) accepts a regex expression, so you can use:

```
"test,string split".split("[, ]")
```

EDIT: Just noticed Reimeus already mentioned this.